# Extract infos from html source?

Tags: java, android, regex, web-scraping

How can I make use of specific information contained in a website?
Right now, I'm getting the `InputStream` of the whole website. Then, trying to extract the useful information with RegEx.

Now I was told RegEx is really bad to extract from HTML.
What else is there with Android?

How can I use and extract specific parts of a website?

Comment: I don't know what "tyvm" means, bu leave such noise out of posts.

Comment: http://www.internetslang.com/TYVM-meaning-definition.asp :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [JSoup library](http://jsoup.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are many situation to parse and extract elements from XML:

- DOM Parsing
- [SAX Parsing](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)
- XML Pull Parser

And there is a nice simply library called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)